# Log Reader replication agents are constantly restarting

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-2000

I am recreating (push) transactional replication from a SQL 2000 instance to a SQL 2008 instance which I had to break in order to do a db migration. The 2008 instance is both the distributor and a subscriber.

About 1/2 of my subscriptions are failing with

> Could not find stored procedure 'sp_MSins_dboTABLE'.

(more info):

> Command attempted: if @@trancount > 0 rollback tran (Transaction
>   sequence number: 0x0002A2B400008D19000100000000, Command ID: 20)
>
> Error messages: Could not find stored procedure
>   'sp_MSins_dboTABLE'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 2812)
>   Get help: Could not find stored procedure
>   'sp_MSins_dboTABLE'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 2812)
>   Get help: 
>   I've chased just about every path I can find, from running `sp_scriptpublicationcustomprocs` (I executed the result in the `distribution` database) to deleting the subscription, then the publication, and then re-creating them.

The working subscriptions were created using the same methodology.

Here are my create scripts:

https://gist.github.com/3152160

Edit:

Update --- My failing subscriptions are also throwing the following error (through Profiler):

> Table already has a primary key defined on it.

Comment: Which database did you migrate, the publisher or the subscriber?

Comment: Migrated the publisher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to reinitialize the subscription which will recreate all the objects on the subscriber.

**EDIT (Added by asker):**

After re-initialization, if there are errors to the effect that it couldn't find a CRUD stored procedure, fire up SQL Profiler and look for errors surrounding that procedure. Make sure you filter the text based on the procedure name from Replication Monitor (It turns out that the command being executed was the stored procedure with a `;2` after it).

Then run `EXEC sp_scriptpublicationcustomprocs 'PublicationName'` on the publisher to get scripts to create the procedure. Create that procedure on the subscriber db including the group number that the process is attempting to run after the group name (e.g. `[sp_MSins_dboTABLE];2`). It feels hacky, but it will get replication functioning healthily again.

Comment: Well well well. When I recreated the publication and added the subscription, I started the snapshot agent. I never actually re-initialized since I didn't believe that it needed it (since I thought I was recreating). Could that be my problem?

Comment: I have reinitialized the subscriptions and I still get the error that it cannot find the stored procedure.

Comment: It sounds like the snapshot isn't being correctly deployed to the subscriber.  Is the table being deleted from the subscriber and recreated?

Comment: I don't believe that they are. At least not automatically. It's been resolved down to two tables now. Reinitialization worked for all but these two

Comment: Ultimately this resolved the majority of my issues. Thank you.

Comment: If the tables aren't being dropped, and you haven't changed the default settings for the articles, then the tables should be getting dropped when the subscription is being initialized.

Comment: At initialization **and** at reinitialization?

Comment: I've edited your answer with a few steps that I had to take to complete resolution. If you'd like, you can edit them in your own words.

Answer (score 0):

Are you up to date on service packs?

Have you looked into this Microsoft support article?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960571

Comment: That looks vaguely similar to my problem. However, the successful subscriptions also have composite keys. Having said that, I'm only at SP1 on my SQL 2008 instance.

Comment: Applying the patch didnt work